# Typo3 extension: Transfering an object via arguments doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, arguments, typo3, extbase

Before i state my problem, please be aware that this is my first time working with Typo3 and/or creating an Extbase extension.

SO basically i want to create an extbase extension for Typo3, but i seem not to be able to wrap my head around the concept of transfering an object (assigned to the view of a specific template) via arguments to an action, with the purpose of attaching the object to another (with a 1:n relation).

My example:

I have an Objekt of the type "Appliance" assigned to the view of a template ("Show.html"). I can list all the properties of it in the Template, so it definitely exists in the view. 
Now i want to create an Object of the type "Host" using a form and then attaching it to this specific "Appliance" object.
The problem is: I can't transfer the object of the type "Appliance" to the specific Action of the Controller of the type "Host" which itself should then assign it to the view of another template.

Look at the following code example:

```
<f:link.action action="new" controller="Host" arguments="{appliance:appliance}" >Add Host X</f:link.action>
```

This is the specific code line in the "Show.html" template that transfers the "Appliance" object to the Action "new" of the "Host" controller using arguments... The "Host" controller:

```
public function newAction(\Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Appliance $appliance, \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Host $host = NULL)
{
$this->view->assign('appliance', $appliance);
$this->view->assign('host', $host);
}
```

At this point i get the following error message:

> "Argument 1 passed to
>   Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Controller\HostController::newAction() must be an
>   instance of Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Appliance, none given"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have two separate plugins, one for `Appliance` and one for `Host` and now try to transfer data between these two?

Comment: What does the link look like that is generated in the Show.html template?

Comment: Whats the docblock for newAction? TYPO3 needs the definition for each method parameter to parse the argument, the type declaration inside the function parameter list isnt enough.

Comment: Just where do i find the docblock? Again: I'm COMPLETELY new to this, just scimmed through some online tutorials and a book. It sucks to be confronted with something completely new at my first day of work.^^

Answer (score 1):

You need a Docblock that describes these parameters. 
What may look like just comments, actually follows the [PHPDoc standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc). These declarations are interpreted by the TYPO3 ReflectionClass to map your Domain Model and validate parameters and object properties.

*Make sure you completely flush the cache whenever you add or update one of these.*

```
/* 
 * @param \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Appliance $appliance
 * @param \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Host $host
 * @return void
 *
 */
public function newAction(\Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Appliance $appliance, \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Host $host = NULL)
{
    $this->view->assign('appliance', $appliance);
    $this->view->assign('host', $host);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a missunderstanding on my side and it may be a stupid question: But where do i put these lines?

 @ param \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Appliance $appliance
 @ param \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Host $host
 @ return void

Comment: These lines go exactly where I put them. Right before the function itself.

Comment: Activating and deactivating the extension seemed to have an effect... Now it shows another error messages:

Call to undefined method FluidCache_Icingaconfgen_Host_action_new_8ac559363f91c5e20ebfcb2b828e8c7e5fbc449d::section_b28b7af69320201d1cf206ebf28373980add1451()

Comment: OK, i just had to rewrite some other lines, now everything works. Thank you very much for the docblock tip... I think without you help i'd have to give up. Thank you, really.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. And: Yup, cache invalidation is one of many things seriously broken in TYPO3. Flushing the whole cache by deleting the typo3temp folder fixes these errors and is, sadly, often the required measure in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that there is an `Appliance` model given in your Fluid template, easily by debugging it before the link with e.g. `<f:debug>{appliance}</f:debug>`

If this is okay, you should add some doc comments above your `newAction` because Extbase is referring to that.

An example would be: (just as I am writing this, a good example was posted). :)

Comment: Man... And i thought these lines were just comments... It seems i have a lot to learn when it comes to Typo3.

Comment: It didn't work....

The variable dump:

Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Applianceprototypepersistent entity (uid=26, pid=8)
   kundeuid => 'test1' (5 chars)
   ipv4extern => '123' (3 chars)
   ipv4intern => '123' (3 chars)
   sshport => '123' (3 chars)
   passwordnsclient => '123' (3 chars)
   passwordappliance => '123' (3 chars)
   hosts => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorageprototypeobject (1 items)
   uid => 26 (integer)
   _localizedUid => 26 (integer)modified
   _languageUid => 0 (integer)modified
   _versionedUid => 26 (integer)modified
   pid => 8 (integer)

Comment: What did you change between your message "It didn't work" and "Everything works now"? :)

Comment: I just deactivated and activated the extension. Also i had to change some other actions in the controller, but that wasn't a problem. The major missunderstanding on my side was that doc block thing, so i definitely learned something yesterday.

Comment: When working with typo3 and extensions you should always clear the cache in the install tool when you change something in your action definitions (and other stuff too)